# Watch OS 6: Can I use lower level sockets on watch os 6?

Tags: sockets, websocket, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I need to use sockets with SSL on watch os 6+. Does it support it? I have legacy code that uses CFStreams. I use CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost function. Everything works fine on the simulator, but does not work on the real device.
I will be glad to hear any suggestions.